# Why does not the weight decrease in an ascending and accelerating lift?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, weight

My textbook says that weight of a person in a lift that is accelerating in upward direction increases.

But,why is it so?

The acceleration of lift and the acceleration due to gravity are in opposite direction.
Hence,weight of the person should be $m(a-g)$(where $m$ is the mass of the person,$a$ is the acceleration of lift and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

Then,where is my serious conceptual flaw?

I have checked [Why do we weigh less when falling?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/49826/why-do-we-weigh-less-when-falling?rq=1.But) I donot find satisfactory explanation of my query there.

Comment: The excess weight is the reaction to the force that the floor has to exert on the person to accelerate them upward, so it points into the same direction as the "force" of gravity, which is defined exactly the same way, as the reaction force to the forces by the floor that prevent us from being in free fall.

Comment: If you release a weight and let it free-fall, it's speed will increase by 32 feet/second for every second it falls.  (Ie, at the end of 2 seconds it will be traveling 64 f/s.)  The falling object will seem (to itself) to be weightless.  If you accelerate downward at a lower speed the object won't be weightless, but will weigh less.  Accelerate upward and it will weigh more than it's non-moving weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked if there's a serious flaw in the assumptions that you're making. The flaw is that Newton's law hold, in its simplest form, in an inertial frame only. So, if you have a lift which is going up with an acceleration $-a$, then you've to introduce a fictitious acceleration $a$ on the body. I have assumed the downward direction to be positive.

So, the net acceleration downward is $a+g$. Always think about the acceleration on the body, rather than on the frame. Once you agree with this, you have the weight being equal to $m(a+g)$, and hence it has increased by $ma$

Answer (score 2):

To weigh nothing, you must be experiencing no acceleration. An object in free fall under the influence of a gravity field experiences no weight, so within its own frame of reference it has no acceleration, although an outside observer would see it accelerating downward. This discrepancy is because, according to Einstein, gravity curves space-time. One can correctly say that a stationary object in a gravity field is accelerating *less* downward (or more upward) than one in free fall. If "no weight" equals "no acceleration", then the stationary object must be in continuous upward acceleration (because of space-time curvature). So, the upward-accelerating elevator is increasing the total acceleration on its contents, causing them to weigh more than they would if stationary, which is what we observe.

Answer (score 1):

As the lift accelerates upward, the reaction force supplied by the floor of the lift upwards to your feet must oppose both your weight and the upwards acceleration of the lift. This is the apparent weight you feel.

Answer (score 0):

There is mass as in F=m X a , and then there is weight. Weight is what m is for the standard g of gravity and is usually  measured on a calibrated weighing scale. On the scale in an accelerator the force the body exerts will be the mg of gravity plus the a*m of the equal and opposite force to the one exerted by the scale on the body. Thus the scale which is calibrated with only gravitational forces will show a larger weight.

Do not confuse mass with weight.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion comes from people using two different definitions of *weight*:

1. **The force on an object by gravity.**  This is the official meaning of weight in physics.  (You can elaborate this definition further, but it does not matter for this discussion.)
2. **The reading when an object is placed on a scale.**  This is what most lay persons would call *weight*.  In physics, *scale reading* would be a better name.

When people weigh themselves on their bathroom scale, these two amounts are the same.  That's because the Earth is essentially an inertial reference frame.  Suppose you weigh 700 N; your weight and the scale reading are both 700 N.

However, in an accelerating reference frame, these two amounts *can* differ.  In an upwardly-accelerating lift, your scale reading will be larger than your weight.  Let's say your weight is still 700 N but the scale now reads 1000 N.

Now consider the forces acting *on you*.  There is the force of gravity, pulling downward -- in fact, it's your weight!  So we have 700 N downward.  There is also the scale under you, pushing upward; by the 3rd Law, it's amount is the scale reading.  So this is 1000 N upward.

What is your net force?  700 N downward + 1000 N upward = 300 N upward.

Your acceleration can be calculated using your mass and the 2nd Law $F_{net}=ma$.  The 2nd Law also tells us that the *direction* of your acceleration is the same as the direction of the net force.  In the previous paragraph, we found that the net force is *upward*.  So your acceleration must be *upward*.

**And this exactly matches the direction of the elevator's acceleration.**

You can perform a similar analysis of a downwardly-accelerating lift, and you will find that Newton's Laws are obeyed when the scale reading is less than the weight.

Sorry it's a late answer, but hope this helps.